# How to integrate this webbrowser code into tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-webbrowser

This is the code I'm trying to integrate into Tkinter:

```
import webbrowser

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
post_url = input("enter your post url : ")
download_url = "en.savefrom.net/"+ post_url
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(download_url)

input("press enter to exit : ")
```

Comment: what kind of GUI do you expect? Just a form? or any special?

Comment: Integrate in what sense? Web broswers general have their own GUI, so how do expect that to mesh with the likely different human interface you likely have in your tkinter app?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser


chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

def downloadFromLink():
    post_url = t.get()
    download_url = "en.savefrom.net/"+ post_url

    try:
        webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(download_url)
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Invalid URL!")

r = Tk()
f = Frame(r)

large_font = ('Verdana',20)
t = StringVar()

label = Label(f ,text = "Enter your post url : ", font = large_font)
label.grid(row = 0)

l1 = Label(f, text = "")
l1.grid(row=1)

postUrl = Entry(f, font = large_font, textvariable = t, width = 30)
postUrl.grid(row = 2)

l2 = Label(f, text = "")
l2.grid(row=3)

downloadButton = Button(f, text = "Download", font = large_font, command = downloadFromLink)
downloadButton.grid(row = 4)

f.pack()
r.mainloop()
```

Hope this help :)